# Export Order Comments from Magento

Tags: magento, export, orders

I am currently searching for a way to add the order comments to order export (.csv format) from a Magento v1.4.2 installation.

I have set up a profile that will export all that I need such as customer name, payment, shipping, etc. using  simple order export and IKT Order Export extensions, but have yet to find a way to export the customer comments/comment history along with the orders.

Is there a simple way of doing this?  The IKT Order Export has a custom mapping field and I have found the table that holds the order comments, but I am not able to get the module to map it.

The comments are in the DB field sales_flat_order_status_history (comments). I am sure it is in the code, but being a relative newbie.... Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can export custom array data to csv easily using Magento's `Varien_File_Csv` class.
If you know the fields to be exported from `sales_flat_order_status_history` then you can simply perform as follow(just a basic idea):

```
<?php
/**
 * @author      MagePsycho <info@magepsycho.com>
 * @website     http://www.magepsycho.com
 */
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$filePath   = '/path-to-csv/comments.csv';
$csv        = new Varien_File_Csv();
$exportData = array(); 
$comments   = getCommentsFromHistoryTable(); //you can fetch comments from the required table
foreach($comments as $_comment){ //loop over the comments to prepare the export data
    $data = array();
    $data['field1'] = $_comment->getField1();
    $data['field2'] = $_comment->getField2();
    //... so on
    $exportData[] = $data;
}
$csv->saveData($filePath, $exportData);
```

That's all. It will save the data in specified csv.

Hope this helps you.
Thanks